# IOS How to remove Zero Width Space [ E2 80 8B ] from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

With copy/paste, one of my clients put in a textfield of my IOS app a text containing Zero Width Space [ E2 80 8B ] and I want to remove them.

here's an example of text : basse ​température ​avec ​dégivrage ​électrique

what I tried :

```
NSString* zarb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c",0xE2,0x80,0x8B];
NSString*resu=[ch stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:zarb withString:@""];
// does not work

if ([ch rangeOfString:zarb].location != NSNotFound) {
      // does not work
}
```

The hexa sequence IS in the string but I cannot remove it.
Someone has already got this problem ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "zero width space" is the Unicode character `\U200B`. The `E2 80 8B` is the UTF-8 encoding.

Try this:

```
NSString* zarb = @"\u200B";
NSString* resu = [ch stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:zarb withString:@""];
```

BTW - your attempt to do:

```
NSString* zarb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c%c%c",0xE2,0x80,0x8B];
```

results in an invalid string because there are no Unicode characters for `80` and `8B`.

Comment: Coooool, many thanks Maddy, it works perfectly with your solution.